# Attempting to install an OS (LINUX) from a flash drive

Tags: system-installation, system

I've never done this before, so please be patient.  I'm not a dummy.  How do I get the flash drive to install it's (LINUX OS) info into a (Goodwill) computer w/o an OS?

Comment: Is this ubuntu you are installing?

Answer (score 0):

When you have proper USB stick, you can boot from it. Reboot PC, enter BIOS settings, openn boot menu (usually it is Del key to enter settings and F8 key for menu). Select your USB stick. If you see options stating UEFI, you must choose among them, not the others.
After you select the proper menu line, you will be propted if you want to install Ubuntu. After that, follow the guides.